# how to stop a function in laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new to LARAVEL. I want to send an AJAX request to a function of controller that this function will run very big loop (takes about 2 minutes). I want to have a button that when click on it, it send a request with AJAX to the controller that stops the function that is running big loop. any idea?

Comment: Submit that function to a [queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues)

Comment: can you give me some example code Mark Barber?

Comment: Start by taking a look at the documentation that I linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After second click (to stop function) you can send to database information about it. In one of 10 loops function can check database and if function get message "stop" then will stopped.

Comment: I think about it. but if there is multiple users that are doing same operation and one of them cancel the operation, all operation of users will cancel!

Comment: You can add additional field which separate users ;)

Comment: yes. but if there is no user! I mean that all people that are running the operation are guest! and I don't have any data about them. I think a better way should exist.

Comment: You have session ID for simple.. or IP. But if you can do better so go code.

Comment: Oh, there is no other solutions :< Maybe queue - @MarkBaker said about it.